# Install packages that have dependencies in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dependencies

I am trying to use dlib library that requires CMake. To do this I include both in the requirements.txt.

Requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
numpy==1.18.4
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
cmake
dlib
```

When I included them both in requirements.txt it gives the following error:

> "ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib".

I found that Cloud Functions installs all the dependencies at the same time and so CMake would have to be already installed in the Google Cloud Function instance.

I also found that we can ask in the Google Cloud [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187183&template=1162821) to have new packages added to the runtime, but is there no other way around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I'd recommend you to use Cloud Run instead of Cloud Functions, where in the image you'll use you can install whatever dependencies you need (in this case, CMake) and you will most likely not run into any unwanted interactions due to concurrency like you've experienced using Cloud Functions.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python) you have a quickstart guide on how to create a Cloud Run service using Python. Hope this is of use to you.

Comment: Hello Roger, that's precisely what I ended up doing and it's working well. Thank you for your help