# Install packages that have dependencies using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-functions, requirements.txt

I am trying to use dlib library that requires CMake, in Google Cloud Functions. To do this I include them both in the requirements.txt.

Requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
numpy==1.18.4
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
cmake
dlib
```

When I included them both in requirements.txt it gives the following error:

> "ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib".

I found that Cloud Functions installs all the dependencies at the same time and so CMake would have to be already installed in the Google Cloud Function instance.

I also found that we can ask in the Google Cloud [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187183&template=1162821) to have new packages added to the runtime, but is there no other way around this?

Thank you

Comment: Consider using Cloud Run instead of Cloud Functions when there are dependencies like the one in your question.

Comment: Hello @JohnHanley! Using Cloud Run I have been able to use dlib and CMake, like you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Please, do not ask the same question just because the previous one was downvoted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67231338

Comment: Hello @Jofre, yes it does answer, that's what I ended up doing and it's working well. Thank you!